# How to get desired courses based on points in ListView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a new Android application where I am supposed to list  like 100 courses in a ListView each with a different points. E.g

(Spanish:24,
English:30,
French:10,
Engineering:20
Law:26
Management:18
Accounting:16
Economics:14 etc...

Now when a student enters her particular point (e.g 22), she will get Engineering, Management, Economics, French, Accounting only! But not English, Spanish, Law. That is, only courses with the same or a lower amount of points will be suitable for her. How can I achieve this?
I was actively looking for some codes following my question and I came across this,but that seems to be incomplete:

Course.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Course extends AppCompatActivity{

private String name;
private int points;

public Course(String name, int points) {
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);


}



    Course[] courses = new Course[]{
    new Course("Medicine", 30),
    new Course("Physics", 28),
    new Course("Math", 24),
    new Course("English", 20)
};


Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
EditText hint =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
searchButton.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

public void onClick(View view) {


        List<Course> courses;
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Course course : courses){
            if (course.getPoints() <= points) {
                courses.add(course);
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = null;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }

activity_main.xml


 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your points"
        android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
      </LinearLayout>

         <ListView
    android:id="@+id/courseNames"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you try to implement `Filterable` in your adapter? http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
    for(Course course : courses){
        if (course.getPoints() <= points) {
            courses.add(c);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thanks freddy :) How about the onClick method and listadapter part to diaplay the desired courses?

Comment: you can get the data you want onClick method, then use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged to refresh listview. you will get the course.

Answer (score 0):

To filter list data you have to implement **Filterable** and Override **getFilter()**  Like below

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new ItemFilter ();
    }

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // Here you need to filter the list on basis of points
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
         //Notify the adapter with filtered data
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: i modified my above please check where i should add your given code. Thanks

Comment: I have check your code but you have not initialize your adapter. You have to create a custom adapter .Please check here for reference

https://gist.github.com/tobiasschuerg/3554252